get the lastest record of an object
I have two models:
Cat (id, name)
CatRecords (id, cat_id, status, created_time)
Each day, a cat have one record about the status of the cat
I want to get all the cats and the latest record of each, sorted by the created_time of the record
I can get all records of each cat, but I cannot get the latest record of each
The query class of Cat:
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_cats = graphene.List(CatType)
    cat = graphene.Field(CatType, cat_id=graphene.UUID())
    latest_record = graphene.Field(CatRecordType)

    def resolve_all_cats(self, info, **kwargs):
        cats = Cat.objects.all()
        return cats

    def resolve_cat(self, info, cat_id):
        return Cat.objects.get(cat_id=cat_id)

    def resolve_latest_record(self, info):
        subquery = CatRecord.objects.filter(cat_id=OuterRef("id")).order_by(
            "-created_time"
        )
        return (
            Cat.objects.all()
            .annotate(latest_record=Subquery(subquery.values("id")[:1]))
            .values("latest_record")
        )

My query
query {
  latestRecord{
    id
    name
  }
}

the error is
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Received incompatible instance \"<QuerySet [{'latest_record': UUID('3d2af716-94aa-4952-9050-4d7f69384e3d')}, {'latest_record': UUID('0705aeda-a2ec-47c3-8bd1-1aa445c40444')}]>\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "latestRecord"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "latestRecord": null
  }
}


We can work with a FilteredRelation [Django-doc] here:
Cat.objects.annotate(
    latest_record=FilteredRelation(
        'catrecords_set',
        condition=Q(
            pk=Subquery(
                CatRecords.objects.filter(cat_id=OuterRef('pk'))
                .order_by('-created_time')
                .values('pk')[:1]
            ),
        ),
    ),
).select_related('latest_record')
This will then fetch the latest CatRecords for each Cat and add that as .latest_record, or None otherwise.


Note: Normally a Django model is given a singular name [django-antipatterns], so CatRecord instead of CatRecords.


Thanks @willeM_ Van Onsem, I have tried your way but the result is null also I have 2 records of 2 cats
https://imgur.com/a/C12JLXE
do you know where else to check?

So that is the crab with the latest record? Can you use print(qs.query) to get the query Django is making (with qs the queryset)?
